# What happens if you call watchPosition and change page without calling clearWatch?

Tags: html, api, geolocation

I am using HTML5 geolocation watchPosition. I have a page that calls watchPosition once that constantly checks the user's location. I am curious what happens if I transfer to another page within the website without calling the clearWatch function. Will watchPosition continue to run and get location data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. All Javascript that was loaded with the page gets discarded and stopped. That includes all event watchers and geolocation watch requests.

The only thing that has even a chance of continuing to run in the background are [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), which you very explicitly need to get up and running.